# ffmpeg with a streaming input change channels order and indices on different execution

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-streaming, mpeg

We're using ffmpeg to take a mpts stream by 3rd party and encode it to a webm file.
Now Every time I've call the `ffmpeg` command I get different map of channels for it.
For example:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp:/.......?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1':   Duration: N/A, start: 37447.088000, bitrate: 1617 kb/s   Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1e00]: Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1020](eng): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1021](spa): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x10c0]: Unknown: none ([134][0][0][0] / 0x0086)   No Program
    Stream #0:4[0x1fff]: Audio: aac, stereo, fltp, 1233 kb/s
```

and next:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@....?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 36871.760000, bitrate: 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1fff]: Unknown: none
    Stream #0:1[0x1021]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1020]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x1e00]: Video: mpeg2video, 90k tbr, 90k tbn
```

or

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@....?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfat                                         al=1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 36861.712000, bitrate: 384 kb/s
  Program 1
  No Program
    Stream #0:0[0x1fff]: Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p
    Stream #0:1[0x1021]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1020]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x1e00]: Video: mpeg2video, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn
```

What I need is a fixed way in order to map those channels and encode them

Comment: Can you provide the actual UDP address?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard It's an internal IP used by our servers

Comment: It probably might not matter too much, but if it's an internal IP why not just post it? Either way, is the order auf audio channels important?

Comment: @slhck They may be english or spanish in this case. the problem that the order may differ.